# A Discrete Mathematics Problem. Any help would be much appreciated!

Tags: logic

In a magic trick four playing cards were stacked together, three of them
face up and one face down, with a heart at the bottom, then a club,
then a diamond, and then a spade (facing down). There are three ways
in which the packet of cards is allowed to be mixed: The packet can be
cut, the top two cards can be turned over as one, or the entire packet
can be turned over together. Prove that for any n ≥ 0 after n allowed
shuffles there will be exactly one card facing the wrong way, that is,
different from the other three.
Not sure exactly where to start. Again, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Use induction!!

Comment: ah okay! so i begin with the base case and go from there?

Comment: Yes. And the base is 0, so that's easy!  For the step, assume that after $n$ shuffles there is exactly 1 card facing differently from the three others, and show that, regardless of what kind of shuffle you do next, you will still have 1 card facing differently from three others.

Comment: that does make sense, but again, i'm not too sure how to go about doing that...

Comment: OK, consider the possible moves: cut the deck: ok, then of course nothing changes in terms of what side the cards face, so there is still 1 card facing differently. Flip the top two. This has 2 subcases: the 1 card that was facing differently is in the top two o

Answer (score 2):

Prove that your operations flip an even number of cards. So if for card $i$ you have:

$
x_i=
\begin{cases}
-1 & \text{if card is face up}\\
1 & \text{if card is face down}\\
\end{cases}
$

then $x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4=-1$ regardless of how many operations you have applied.

Comment: hmm okay, that does make sense. thank you! :)